# How to register a java.util.List type in Apache Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is it possible to use `Environment#registerType` for `java.util.List` or other collection types?
If I do:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

env.getConfig().disableGenericTypes();
env.registerType(List.class);
```

I still get `Generic types have been disabled in the ExecutionConfig and type java.util.List is treated as a generic type.`

What I acutally would like to do, but what is not possible in Java, because of type erasure is:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

env.getConfig().disableGenericTypes();
env.registerType(List<MyClass>.class);
```

Unfortunately, I found no solution in the documentation or using a search engine.

Comment: why you disable generic types first and then register a generic type?

Comment: I do not want generic types. I would like to register the specific type if possible. Something like `env.registerType(List<MyClass>.class)`. But, because of type erasure, this is not possible in Java.

Comment: I've editted the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

How about implements `List<T>` like

```
class MyClassList implements List<MyClass> {
...
}
```

then you can registerType Type `MyClassList` with specifict `MyClass`

Comment: Currently I believe I am not using Flink correctly and should not pass `java.util.List` objects around. I'll however try your proposal as soon as possible and will give you a checkmark if it works.

Comment: i have tried the solution but it didn't worked